How to use structlog with logfmt formatted logs in python?
I want to print out root logs in logfmt format. structlog also should print logs in the same format. I tried this example for JSON format and looks like it doesn't work with logfmt.
Here is a first try:
import logging
import sys

import logfmter
import structlog

handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setFormatter(logfmter.Logfmter())
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.addHandler(handler)

structlog.get_logger("test").warning("hello")
logging.getLogger("test").warning("hello")

It prints:
2024-06-04 22:11:01 [warning  ] hello                         
at=WARNING msg=hello

Here is structlog is definitely not a logfmt formatted.
I tried to add logfmt render then:
import logging
import sys

import logfmter
import structlog

handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setFormatter(logfmter.Logfmter())
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.addHandler(handler)

structlog.configure(
    processors=[
        structlog.stdlib.filter_by_level,
        structlog.stdlib.add_logger_name,
        structlog.stdlib.add_log_level,
        structlog.stdlib.PositionalArgumentsFormatter(),
        structlog.processors.TimeStamper(fmt='iso'),
        structlog.processors.StackInfoRenderer(),
        structlog.processors.format_exc_info,
        # ADD LOGFMT RENDER
        structlog.processors.LogfmtRenderer(),
    ],
    logger_factory=structlog.stdlib.LoggerFactory(),
    wrapper_class=structlog.stdlib.BoundLogger,
    cache_logger_on_first_use=True,
)

structlog.get_logger("test").warning("hello")
logging.getLogger("test").warning("hello")

And fail again:
at=WARNING msg="event=hello logger=test level=warning timestamp=2024-06-04T13:12:54.637931Z"
at=WARNING msg=hello

Obviously correct log line should be like:
at=WARNING msg=hello logger=test level=warning timestamp=2024-06-04T13:12:54.637931Z

Is it possible to format both structlog and logging as logfmt?

If you want to have the same output in standard library and structlog, you have to integrate them. That is sadly not trivial, but is something that has to be done only once.
The documentation gives a bunch of examples for the same problem in JSON, so you can pick the approach that you like most: https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/standard-library.html#suggested-configurations
Bear in mind that just not integrating and configuring stdlib to do a similar-enough thing to structlog is always an option too.
